# KeyError in Python when deleting a key from dictionary, but key exists

Tags: python, keyerror

I am trying to remove a key from a dictionary using the value from another key. The key exists, it says it exists when I type `value in dict.keys()`, but I get the keyerror when I try to delete it.

```
def remove_duplicate_length(choices):
    print choices
    print choices['scheme']
    print type(choices['scheme'])
    print choices['scheme'] in choices.keys()
    print 'AABB' in choices.keys()
    scheme = choices['scheme']
    print type(scheme)
    del choices[scheme]
```

Prints this:

```
{'ABAB': '2', 'AABB': '6', 'scheme': 'AABB', 'authors': ['Bukowski']}
AABB
<type 'str'>
True
True
<type 'str'>
None
```

And gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` when trying to reference the result of the return statement, or `keyerror: AABB` when trying to directly print the result.

I'm printing the result like this:

```
@route('/', method='POST')
def getUserChoice():
    user_selection = parse_data(request.body.read())
    print user_selection
```

Comment: how are you trying to print the result ?

Comment: `del choices['scheme']`

Comment: The `None` is because `del` does not give you a return type. If you inspect `choices`, you would see that this key is not in the dict anymore

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `choices = remove_duplicate_length(choices)`? Your function does not return a dict. It mutates it "by reference".

Comment: What `return` statement are you talking about?  Python doesn't implicitly return the result of the last command like some other languages, and even if it did, the `del` statement only returns None.

Comment: Rogalski is correct, I had a return statement within the function which returns nothing, only creates side effects

Answer (score 1):

Python `dict` has a very util method, `get`. Let's say that your dictionary may have, or not, a key. You can use `get` to retrieve it's key or something else, then you can check if result satisfy your condition.

```
>>> mydict = {'name': 'Jhon', 'age': 2}
>>> mydict.get('name')
Jhon
>>> mydict.get('lastname', 'Not found')
Not found
```

In your method, you can check if key exists, and then, delete it.

```
...
scheme = choices.get('scheme', None)
print type(scheme)
if scheme:
    del choices[scheme]
```